# Proof of an Isomorphic map with respect to a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am having a really hard time understand the proof of this theorem:

Let $(V,W)$ be a pair of finite dimensional vector spaces, and let $B(v,w)$ be a non-degenerate bilinear form on $V\times W \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$. For fixed $w \in W$ let $\phi_w(v)=B(v,w), v \in V$, and the mapping $\Phi: W \rightarrow V^*$ defined by $\Phi(w)=\phi_w$ is an isomorphism of $W$ onto $V^*$.

I am confused because how is a pair of mappings an isomorphism, and at three points in the proof: namely, (1) they prove the surjectivity of $\Phi$ by showing that $\dim V^*=\dim W$; how does this show surjectivity? and (2), they say that $\Phi$ being 1-1 implies that $\dim V^* \geq \dim W$ and further (3), that if we reapply the non-degeneracy of $B$ we see that a 1-1 and linear transformation of $V$ into $W^*$; why is this the case?

Also, in the proof they note that the mapping $w \mapsto \phi_w $ is a linear transforation. Which I am assuming they mean $\Phi(w)$ for $w \mapsto \phi_w $. If this is the case, why does one need to show surjectivity, I thought that a linear transformation was injective iff it is surjective?...

Also, if anyone has a link to a very understandable proof, I would apprectiate it.

Comment: You want `\to`, not `\arrow`.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks, man.

Comment: @janmarqz The theroem in my book says (V,W) is a pair of vector spaces not L(V,W)...

Comment: They probably meant that if $\Phi$ is surjective, then $\dim V^* \leq \dim W$.  Or, by the rank nullity theorem: if $\dim V^* = \dim W$, then a map from $V^*$ to $W$ will be surjective iff it is injective.

Comment: @phatty, usually a mathematician  uses $L(V,W)$ for all the linear maps $V\to W$ and $V\times  W$ as a domain of bilinear forms... but if this doesn't help please feel free to re-modify

Answer (score 3):

For any fixed $w \in W$ we have that $\phi_w$ is a linear map because $B$ is bilinear (that is, exactly, is linear in each argument). So we obtain a map $ W \to V^*$ recalling that $V^*$ is tha linear space of linear maps $V \to \mathbb{F}$.

Non-degeneracy of $B$ guarantees that $\Phi$ is injective because if $\Phi(w) = 0$ means that $B(v,w) = 0$ for every $v \in V$, but $B$ is non-degerate so $w = 0$. Having proved injectivity, we have that $dim W \leq dim V^*$

On the other hand we can prove the same thing for a map $\Psi: V \to W^*$ fixing the first argument of $B$. Equally we can prove that this is an injective linear map, so $dim V \leq dimW^*$.

But for any finite dimensional vector space $dim V = dimV^*$ so that $dimW = dimV$ and both $\Psi$ and $\Phi$ are isomorphisms.